# Where to find Qt's commits?

Tags: git, qt, commit

There's a regression in Qt 4.6.2 on Windows (setting border color from stylesheet does not work) that I decided to fix myself.

This bug was originally reported in Qt 4.4, and was fixed in Qt 4.5, around December 2008. Unfortunately I cannot find the corresponding commit in http://code.qt.io/cgit/, probably because the commit is anterior to the switch to Git (or it was made during the transition).

Where I can find this commit?

Cheers,
Franz

---

For reference:

- New ticket for the regression: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the older repository ("qt-history") has never been public, and doesn't exist anymore:

https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/03/27/happy-birthday-mr-repository/

Answer (score 0):

Can you narrow down the Qt versions, to find one where the problem existed, and then a later one, where it was fixed? If you can find a reference to the bug in the [Qt Version Changes](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/changes/) page, this will you give you the exact pair of versions you want.

If so, I've found that, with this information, I can usually locate the changes for a bug-fix by downloading the source code for 2 different versions of Qt, and then comparing the relevant source files.

A diff'ing tool like Meld or Araxis Merge can be really useful for this.